# How do I find the current through the 5 ohm resistor?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I'm not sure if I'm even doing this correctly. I used Delta-Star transformation and managed to find the total current. How do I find the current through the 5 ohm resistor after that?

Comment: You only calculated the total current that is drawn by the whole circuit. Not the current that is flowing through a 5-ohm resistor. https://tinyurl.com/27va868k

Comment: I would use the Thevenin theorem to find the current. https://tinyurl.com/2c5d5o5q

Comment: @G36 I know I found the total current. I have no clue how to find the current through the 5 ohm resistor. That's my question. The question never specified which method to use so I suppose I could use Thevenin's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want mesh (KVL), so starting at **F** for \$I_1\$, starting at **E** for \$I_2\$, and starting at **D** for \$I_3\$, then working clockwise for each:

$$\begin{align*}
0\:\text{V}&-3\:\Omega\cdot\left(I_1-I_3\right)-3\:\Omega\cdot I_1-4.5\:\Omega\cdot I_1-5\:\Omega\cdot\left(I_1-I_2\right)&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V}&-6\:\Omega\cdot\left(I_2-I_3\right)-5\:\Omega\cdot\left(I_2-I_1\right)-4.5\:\Omega\cdot I_2-3\:\Omega\cdot\left(I_2-I_3\right)&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V}&+24\:\text{V}-3\:\Omega\cdot\left(I_3-I_1\right)-6\:\Omega\cdot\left(I_3-I_2\right)-3\:\Omega\cdot\left(I_3-I_2\right)&=0\:\text{V}
\end{align*}$$

Using [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) find:

```
e1 = Eq( 0 - 3*(i1-i3) - 3*i1 - 4.5*i1 - 5*(i1-i2), 0 )        # KVL loop 1
e2 = Eq( 0 - 6*(i2-i3) - 5*(i2-i1) - 4.5*i2 - 3*(i2-i3), 0 )   # KVL loop 2
e3 = Eq( 0 + 24 - 3*(i3-i1) - 6*(i3-i2) - 3*(i3-i2), 0 )       # KVL loop 3
ans = solve( [ e1, e2, e3 ], [ i1, i2, i3] )
ans
{i1: 1.66459627329193, i2: 2.55900621118012, i3: 4.33540372670807}
```

The magnitude of the current is then:

```
abs(ans[i2]-ans[i1])
0.894409937888199
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

> *How do I find the current through the 5 Ohm resistor?*

It seems to me you made a good start then missed a trick: -

[image]

I just used source transformations to convert the 24 volts on one side and the 24 volts on the other side. In other words, one side is powered from a separate 24 volts to the other side (providing you keep a reference connection).

I calculate current to be 0.8946 amps.

Comment: Oooh I see. I didn't know that you could just split the voltage like that. I just started engineering soooo !

Comment: Yes, it's a tried and tested method @AparajitaPal. So, if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.